# script to copy one file into multiple folders and subfolders

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I've been trying to copy a single file to various folders and subfolders at once, and I've been somewhat successful so far using this script:

```
@echo off
for  /D  %%a  in ("c:\folder\folder 1\*.*") do xcopy  /y  /d  c:\test\file.exe "%%a\"
```

this works just fine and copies my file into every folder that's inside "folder 1", but the problem is that I have "folder 2", "folder 3" and so on with various others folders inside them, and I wanted the script to copy my file to all of them at once, instead of having to edit the script every time I want to copy my file into the subfolders

Comment: Open up a Command Prompt window and enter `for /?`. Alternatively open open up a Command Prompt window and enter `dir /?`. You will need to use one or both of these commands.

Comment: `for /D /R "C:\folder" %%D in ("*") do xcopy /Y /D "C:\test\file.exe" "%%~D\"`

Comment: @aschipfl perfect, thank you very much

Comment: @aschipfl no explanation ???
kindly provide a brief explanation for us to learn.

Comment: @MedicalDoctor-Programmer, Compo's comment should provide all info you need; in addition, take a look at [`for /R`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)…